# Floats/graphics’ margins in pdflscape with afterpage

Tags: margins, double-sided, includegraphics, scrbook, pdflscape

I am currently working on a lengthy scrbook document that includes many graphics (images, music scores, etc.). At one particular side, I have a left (even) page full of text, then using `\afterpage`as a way to make the text/figure wrap up as neatly looking as possible. On the right side of the same doublepage, there is a full page figure, followed by three more pages with  `pdflscapes`and two figures on each side.
My problem are the following two:
(1) When I compile the document, there appears a large white space under the first figure [image].

Is it possible to get some of the text that continues a few pages later already in this space?

(2) The following landscape pages appear fine at first sight, keeping two figures at a page and leaving the page number just where it’s supposed to be (the document is for printing, that’s why).

[image]

However, even if I manually crop the images, there are large margins on the new top and bottom of the pages that I seem to cannot make smaller (they should be 2.7cm on each side with a bindingoffset of .3cm. Furthermore, the alternating header lets the figures float around too much. Finally, the very last figure seems to not work at all, stretching across the page. Is there any way how I can normalize the margins and save the last image?

This is my code (hopefully not too much for a MWE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,USenglish,bulgarian,russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.1cm,right=4.5cm,headheight=14.5pt,footnotesep=1cm,bindingoffset=.3cm,marginparsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[paragraph]{section}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
   some text
    \afterpage{\newgeometry{top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3cm,right=2.7cm,bindingoffset=.3cm}\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ex/Werke/Bojanskijatmajstor/969-1039/969-1039-1.jpeg}}\afterpage{\clearpage
                \begin{landscape}
                \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{ex/Werke/Bojanskijatmajstor/969-1039/969-1039-2.jpeg}
                \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{ex/Werke/Bojanskijatmajstor/969-1039/969-1039-3.jpeg}
                \clearpage
                
                \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{ex/Werke/Bojanskijatmajstor/969-1039/969-1039-4.jpeg}
                \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{ex/Werke/Bojanskijatmajstor/969-1039/969-1039-5.jpeg}
                \clearpage
                
                \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{ex/Werke/Bojanskijatmajstor/969-1039/969-1039-6.jpeg}
                \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{ex/Werke/Bojanskijatmajstor/969-1039/969-1039-7.jpeg}
                \clearpage
            \end{landscape}}
```

some more text \end{document}

Comment: Actually, a good MWE would not use any inaccessable graphic files (ex/Werke/Bojanskijatmajstor/969-1039/969-1039-2.jpeg).  Normally we would use variation of example-image, but \rule would do if you knew the height and width.

Comment: Do you want text to appear below the first figure, or just center it in the page?  BTW, you could probably use sigewaysfigure instead of \afterpage{\landscape...}.  Also, it is easier to overlap margins than change them.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks for your reply. I’m not sure about the height and width of my images, how can I find out about them?
I would like to let text appear below the first figure. However, if there is too little space, I wouldn’t mind it appearing after the entire sequence of figures.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with sidewaysfigure and it worked quite well. The only remaining problem is that the sidewayfigures are flushed to the outer side of the page, a \noindent doesn’t help. Given the concrete graphic files I’m using, I suspect this only happens on even pages.

Comment: You can use something like \sbox0{\includegraphics{...}} and print \the\ht0 and \the\wd0.  If you want text under the first image, you definitely cannot use \newgeometry, as the text (stored in \AP@partial0 was formatted using the old geometry, not to mention the automatic \clearpage before and after a geometry change.  Which margins do you want to overlap?

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks a lot for your comment! :) I would just like to let the figure overlap over the outer page margin. This margin is currently set at 4.5cm, with overlapping figures it would be great if the “new” outer margin is only 2.1cm.

Comment: Add `\hspace*{-2.4cm}` to whichever side you want to overlap.  Or use `\makebox[\textwidth][l]{...}` to overlap the right margi ([r] for left margin).  For even/odd, you can use `\ifodd\value{page} ...\fi` with `\afterpage`.  Otherwise see the ifoddpage package.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Everything works well, now!